# USB tethering not working after using MirrorLink

Tags: applications

Sharing was workink fine until I started using MirrorLink. Now when I try to share internet via USB cable i get greyed-out option saying "Port USB is used by MirrorLink". When i go to MirrorLink tab i get greyed-out option too, saying "USB tethering is turned on".  It looks like the Apps are fighting over USB connection. Can I somehow prioritize USB? I tried to turn off MirrorLink app but It didn´t fix the problem. Any ideas what should I try next?
(The pictures are in Slovakia language if you want something to translate just let me know)

[image: MirrorLink settings]

[image: USB tethering settings]

Comment: Try clean cache MirrorLink because fix your tethering issue first then look forward to app

Comment: And give a translation as google translator isn't working well (minor errors) for all languages